# Animation file format

Tags: c++, animation

I'm trying to make a simple 2D animation file format. It'll be very rudimentary: only an XML file containing some parameters (such as frame duration) and metadata, and some images, each representing a frame.

I'd like to have the whole animation (frames and XML document) packed in a single file. How do you suggest I do that? What libraries are there that would allow easy access to the files inside the animation file itself?

The language I'm using is C++ and the platform is Windows, but I'd rather not use a platform dependent library, if possible.

Comment: If you don't need it to be a vector images, how about an animated .gif? No XML, but you can specify frame durations.

Comment: I want something more flexible than that. I might have to speed up the animation in the game at some points.

Comment: Then go with SVG. It's xml-based and scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) for that, lua is 100% cross-platform, the library is about 150 KB, and you can easily describe what you need. It's a lot more comfortable than XML for your needs, less verbose, etc.

Comment: I'm not looking for a scripting language (I'm already going o be using Python, anyway). I'm looking for a way to pack the animation files together and be able to read them from inside the pack easily.

Comment: Lua is not only a good scripting language, it's also an amazing data description language ( very similar to JSON )